# Is it possible to use an int[] to create Foo[] where Foo takes that int into the constructor using a stream. Java 11

Tags: java

Basically I have an array of integers and I need to change that to an array of an object which takes an integer for the constructor. I was just wondering if this was possible using a stream in java 11.

Comment: Yes it is. Maybe not a good SO question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int input[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
YourClass[] output = IntStream.of(input)
        .mapToObj(YourClass::new)
        .toArray(YourClass[]::new);
```

Comment: `IntStream#of()` just calls `Arrays#stream()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use mapToObj on the int stream:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] ints = {1,2,3,4};
        Foo[] foos = Arrays.stream(ints).mapToObj(Foo::new).toArray(Foo[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foos));
    }
    
}

record Foo(int no) {
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo no:" + no;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Foo no:1, Foo no:2, Foo no:3, Foo no:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
int[] arr = ....;
Foo[] foos = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().map(e -> new Foo(e)).toArray(size -> new Foo[size]);
```

or

```
int[] arr = ....;
Foo[] foos = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().map(Foo::new).toArray(Foo[]::new);
```